# How much weight can these wood bedside drawers support?

Tags: wood

This is less of a showcase display of fine woodwork and more of a question on the stability of certain drawers.
I intend to place a cabinet on top of a bedside drawer, I'm worried that the drawers I plan on purchasing will not be able to support the amount of weight of the cabinet.

So my question is whether these drawers are able to support a cabinet of 50kg/110 pounds.

https://www.fantasticfurniture.com.au/Categories/Bedroom-%26-Mattresses/Bedroom/Bedside-Tables/Avoca-Bedside-2-Drawer/p/AVOBSD2DWOOOFOICHO

https://www.fantasticfurniture.com.au/Categories/Bedroom-%26-Mattresses/Bedroom/Bedside-Tables/Groove-Bedside-Table-/p/GROBSD2DWOOOMDFCBR

I am not the best at estimating or guessing how much weight a bedside drawer can support so I figured I'd ask for some knowledgeable assistance!

Kind Regards

Comment: There's no way to answer this without actual knowledge of the slides used. Enquiring directly from the manufacturer would be the best way to find that out.

Comment: @Matt  Although similar in nature, I think this one will address different concerns that your possible duplicate. Most notably how the cabinet mounts and the details regarding the drawer glides.

Comment: I think your question is meaning to ask how much the bedside table itself can support, and not how much the drawers can support. You mention that you intend to place a cabinet on top of it, which is what leads me to think this. In that case, I would not rely on this table to support something that heavy long term, as you cannot attest to the quality of construction.

In the case of how much the drawers can actually support, those type of epoxy mounted slides are most often rated at 100lbs for the pair, but the drawer bottom itself will likely fail before that weight.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate of the other cabinet question since it seems like this question is specifically asking about the weight capacity of the top of a table or cabinet with drawers, and the answers on that question should be applicable here, as well.  @CoconutPie1 if you had something more specific in mind, please edit this question appropriately or request some assistance clarifying it in chat or on meta.